# Forest plot with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I'm trying to create a 'Forest Plot' in TikZ. An example of this is below:

[image: Forest Plot]

I have experience with PGFPlots but I can't find an example or even a starting point for something like this. The only way I can think of is to draw this using low-level TikZ with absolute positioning. However, I'm almost sure there has to be a better way.

All I'm looking for is some ideas for strategy on how to draw this best when ther are 100+ rows. Then, I can try it out and come back with specific questions.

p.s. Explanation of the plot. Every "row" is defined by 3 numbers. The point in the middle is the mean, it extends to either side by two numbers which might not be equal and give 95% CI.

Comment: It is called error plot. Check the `error bars` section (page 259) of `pgfplots` manual.

Comment: Umm, thanks but I did take a look at that. I'm not sure if `error bars` serves the purpose here. The rows are independent of each other and there is no linearity on the x-axis. Maybe I'm completely misreading the text here. `:(`

Comment: Well, seeing the answer, you were right (of course). Just outside my skill level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way using `pgfplot`'s error bars:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{filecontents}{data.txt}
y x plusError minusError
sigma 0.55 0.05 0.1
sigmaLog -0.7 0.1 0.1
gamma 0.1 0.2 0.2
beta -0.1 0.1 0.1
alpha 1.7 1.2 1.2
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ytick=data, yticklabels from table={data.txt}{y}, grid=both, 
               width=\textwidth, height=10cm, axis background/.style={fill=gray!20},
               major grid style={white}, xtick={-1,0,...,3}, tick style={draw=none},
               separate axis lines, axis line style={draw opacity=0}, title={\large 95\% Credible Intervals}]
    % Confidence intervals
    \addplot [blue, only marks, mark=*, error bars/.cd, error mark=none, x dir=both, x explicit]
             table [x=x, y expr=\coordindex, x error plus=plusError, x error minus=minusError] {data.txt};
    % 0 line
    \draw [thick, dashed] (0, -5) -- (0, 5);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I did quite a lot of customizing to match your image exactly, the part you really want is the tick settings passed to `axis` and the `\addplot` command. The only hard coded part is the vertical line, but it's easy to change that (just modify the coordinates to make it longer).

Comment: That is amazing man. I will need some time to understand the code and fix it for many rows but it seems to be working well for a small number of rows.

Comment: For me, the code posted does not work.  I need to change {draw opacity=0} to {draw opacity=100}, or at least {draw opacity=x} where x is positive.  I don't know whether that's because of an idiosyncrasy of my setup.